# How to sort Good+Recent questions

Tags: support, questions

There is currently a flood of boring questions by new users. It has been a while since I have seen some interesting questions. But then I realised many of the recent interesting questions might get lost to the bottom of the "newest" tab in the current flood of questions.

Is there a way I can sort out these "Good" questions which are recent enough(A week old)?

Note that the "frequent" or "votes" tabs don't help because they don't sort out the recent ones. And the "newest" tab doesn't help because it doesn't sort out the good ones.

**Edit:** Though it doesn't need specifying, "good" questions are defined by votes and/or activity(views, comments, etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the search box at the top right, you can write `is:question score:3` and then sort the results by "newest". This will give you a list of all questions with net score 3 or higher, sorted from newest to oldest. You can, of course, change the number 3 to some other value to suit your definition of a good question.

There are also search operators for views and number of answers and other things, if you would like to incorporate those; full details are [in the help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

P.S. Don't forget that you can help limit the number of boring questions (and the visibility of the ones we do get) by downvoting and/or flagging them when it's appropriate to do so. Downvotes and flags, properly used, are an essential part of keeping the site's quality up.

Comment: Downvote a boring question? Is that appropriate? I might downvote an incorrect question or a poorly worded one, but not a boring one, because it might be interesting to someone else.

Comment: @udiboy well your votes are really yours to use as you want. Except for serial voting and countervoting, you can upvote or downvote whenever you think it's appropriate. That being said, I thought you were talking about questions where the OP is asking about something simple and easily available elsewhere. Those I definitely recommend downvoting. If a question is boring to you simply because you're not interested in that particular subject, then you're right, I would recommend not downvoting it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `score:` search operator to filter by score, and then sort the results by "newest" or "active". Try [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=score:3%20is:question) search (modify the number 3 if you wish).

There also is a `views:` operator (and an `answers:` operator) that works similarly. Both operators search for posts with score/views greater than or equal to a given number.